# Django: How to return None if any values in a queryset annotation is null

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want to do a annotation on a Django queryset. If any of the values are Null, the total returned should be None.

I always thought that is the default, but it doesn't seem to be the case. See example below:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Player(models.Model):
    score = models.FloatField(null=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

n = Team.objects.create(name='north')
s = Team.objects.create(name='south')

Player.objects.create(team=n, score=10) 
Player.objects.create(team=s, score=20)
Player.objects.create(team=s)

qs = Team.objects.all().annotate(total=Sum('player__score'))

for t in qs:
    print(t, t.total)
>>> north 10  # This is expected
>>> south 20  # This should give None, because the third player doesn't have a score
```

How can I get the desired behaviour in the calculation?

I'm using Django 1.11.18 with Postgres

Comment: I don't understand "it's easy to check when using an aggregation, but not easy when using an annotation". Where are you using an annotation? There isn't any in your question. And what is easy? The example you show is an aggregation, so why is it easy?

Comment: @dirkgroten Example updated